# Iterating a list of items and append () html if the text of the item corresponds to "something" (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of items, and I would like:
  if the text of an item corresponds to another text, then I have to add in a span with a class (class is an icon font).

```
<div id="block-system-main-menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mappe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Vulc</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Equa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
 </ul>   
</div>
```

Strangely however adds the class to to all the items and I do not understand why ....

```
 $('#block-system-main-menu li').each(function () {
                if (($(this).children().text()) == 'Mappe' || 'Vulc' || 'Equa'){
                    $(this).append('<span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>');
                }               
            });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/wm39fdht/1/)**

Because your condition satisfies for all the scenarios. You need to separate the concern in `or` condition:

```
$('#block-system-main-menu li').each(function () {
   var text=$(this).find('a').text(); //get the a's text using find and store it as 
   //reference in variable
   if (text == 'Mappe' || text== 'Vulc' || text== 'Equa'){
        $(this).append('<span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>');
   }               
});
```

Comment: Anytime... Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below snippet. You have to check for each text as follows:

```js
$('#block-system-main-menu li').each(function () {
  
                if (($(this).children().text()) == 'Mappe' || $(this).children().text() =='Vulc' || $(this).children().text() =='Equa'){
                    $(this).append('<span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>');
                }               
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block-system-main-menu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mappe</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Vulc</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Equa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>  
 </ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
$('#block-system-main-menu li').each(function () {
var _getCondition =$(this).children().text()
if (_getCondition == 'Mappe' || _getCondition == 'Vulc' || _getCondition== 'Equa'){
  $(this).append('<span class="fa fa-caret-right">Hello</span>');
   }
```

});

Added hello in span just for validation

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjd3w15y/)